# HTML5 Audio tag with JQuery audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#play-bt").click(function(){
                    $(".audio-player")[0].play();
                    $(".message").text("Music started");
                })

                $("#pause-bt").click(function(){
                    $("#audio-player")[0].pause();
                    $(".message").text("Music paused");
                })

                $("#stop-bt").click(function(){
                    $(".audio-player")[0].pause();
                    $(".audio-player")[0].currentTime = 0;
                    $(".message").text("Music Stopped");
                })
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <audio class ="audio-player" name="" src="01-Breakin-A-Sweat-Zedd-Remix.mp3" ></audio>
        <audio class ="audio-player" name="" src="04-zedd-stars_come_out_(terravita_remix)" ></audio>

                <div class ="message"></div>
            <a id = "play-bt" href="#">Play music</a> | <a id ="pause-bt" href="#">Pause music</a> | <a id ="stop-bt" href="#">Stop music</a> 

    </body>
</html>
```

This code only plays the first audio tag, how will I be able to play the next song/track/audio tag?

Comment: You're using `$(".audio-player")[0]`, that gets the 1st tag.  What trouble are you having with getting the other one?

Comment: Oh I see that's what its for btw may I ask where did Jquery got this method? .play(); ?

Comment: That's not a jQuery method.  It's a native DOM method.  The `[0]` gets the native DOM element from the jQuery object.

Comment: where can I see the library of the DOM for audio elements?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLMediaElement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the audio elements loaded are in an array, which you can access using the methods you have. If you add a next track function you can browse through all the elements, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var x = $(".audio-player").length; // Count total audio players
    var z = 0; // Start at first audio player

    $("#play-bt").click(function(){
        $(".audio-player")[z].play();
        $(".message").text("Music started");
    })
    $("#pause-bt").click(function(){
        $("#audio-player")[z].pause();
        $(".message").text("Music paused");
    })
    $("#stop-bt").click(function(){
        $(".audio-player")[z].pause();
        $(".audio-player")[z].currentTime = 0;
        $(".message").text("Music Stopped");
    })
    $("#next-bt").click(function(){
        $(".audio-player")[z].pause();
        z++;
        if (z >= x) z = 0;
        $(".audio-player")[z].play();
        $(".message").text("Track: "+z);
    })
})​
```

It finds the amount of audio elements with jquery .length, and when you reach the last track it starts from the first one. Here's an example -> http://jsfiddle.net/8GycB/46/

Comment: The audio elements are actually in a jQuery object (which pretends to be an array).